# reducing automation effects using design

Tags: application-state

I'm involved in a project where user actions are translated to automatic flow.

*Previous state*: the user had to read the info, analyze it  and take an action.

*Current state*: the user reads a summary of the info, looks at the suggestion of the computer and only needs to approve\edit the computer's action.

Are there known design patterns that handle the negative effects created by automation (for example loosing the ability to cognitive analyze information)?

Answer (score 1):

I think you'll find a bunch of relevant papers if you search for [Improving Situational Awareness](https://www.google.co.il/search?q=improving%20situational%20awareness).

For instance:

[Designing for Situation Awareness: An Approach to User-Centered Design](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/1420063553)

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Losing the ability for a human to analyze the situation isn't a drawback, as long as the computer makes better decisions than a human. In any case, you should also build manual override, which allows the human to view the complete information and make decisions like before the automated decision maker was there.